# How can I extract a selected row's data on Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have initialised a simple Datatable:

```
//initialise table
var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    searching: false,
    responsive: true

});
//hide unnecessary columns
dataTable.columns(1).visible(false);
dataTable.columns(2).visible(false);
dataTable.columns(3).visible(false);
dataTable.columns(4).visible(false);
dataTable.columns(5).visible(false);
dataTable.columns(6).visible(false);
dataTable.columns(7).visible(false);
dataTable.columns(8).visible(false);
```

It can contain any number of records but I would like to take the values from all of the columns (only 1 is displayed to the user) and insert them into input fields (which may or may not be visible).  I have successfully been able to select the rows using:

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

       if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
           $(this).removeClass('selected');
       }
       else {
           dataTable.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
           $(this).addClass('selected');
       }

   });
```

I have been looking into the Datatables API, `row()`, `cells()` etc and whilst I can view the `data()` method I simply can't see how to extract data from EACH cell on the row into the input text fields on the same webpage.  I have also looked at  `fnGetSelectedData` but I didn't get far as it always returned undefined via the console.

To explain the use case, it's essentially an Address Lookup. Each column in the table represents part of the address, I want to take the cells from the selected row and insert it into the form as a users selected address.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't get your question. [`rows().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()) and [`row().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) are the right way to do this. They both return arrays ordered by column, and it should be easy to work with that, right?

Comment: So within the click function, I should be using row().data() to return the data?  Essentially I want to be able to grab all of the cells on a selected row and insert it into a text field.  I am a bit of a newbie and appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, row().data() is how you do it. Gyrocode's answer more than covers it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

Use the code below to get data for the selected row:

```
var data = $('#example').DataTable().row('.selected').data();
```

Then you can populate your input fields as shown below:

```
$('#name').val(data[0]); 
$('#email').val(data[1]);
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzwvedx6/) for demonstration.

#### NOTES

You can simplify your initialization code:

```
var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    searching: false,
    responsive: true
    columnDefs: [
       {
          targets: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
          visible: false
       }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the notes, that has worked a treat and it is easier.  I have also tried the solution but it reports "data" is undefined when I reference it like data[1].  Bit of a newbie so I appreciate the help.  I was pointed to this API page but struggling to get it working: http://datatables.net/extensions/select/integration

Comment: @n34_panda, since you're not using Select extension the link doesn't apply to you. If you use Select extension, see [this example](http://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html). I also added a simple [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzwvedx6/) to demonstrate the code.

Comment: Yup, perfect - I don't know why I struggled 30 mins ago.  I have got to a different PC and it worked first time.  Really appreciate the detail, explanation and fiddle for the help.